# In R create new column with name of column closest in value to target

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm analyzing donor data from an appeal. Let's say we have this data frame, which has an ID, the amount given, and the ask amounts from an appeal card:

```
dfgive <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
   gift = c(20, 1000, 1500, 300, 500),
   ask1 = c(50, 5000, 5000, 100, 2500),
   ask2 = c(100, 3750, 3750, 250, 5000),
   ask3 = c(250, 2500, 2500, 500, 10000),
   gift_diff_1 = c(-30, -4000, -3500, 200, -2000),
   gift_diff_2 = c(-80, -2750, -2250, 50, -4500),
   gift_diff_3 = c(-230, -1500, -1000, -200, -9500),
   mindiff = c(-230, -4000, -3500, -200, -9500))
```

The gift difference from each ask amount and the minimum difference were created with the code below.

```r
mutate(gift_diff_1 = gift - ask1) %>%
   mutate(gift_diff_2 = gift - ask2) %>%
   mutate(gift_diff_3 = gift - ask3) %>%
   mutate(mindiff=min(gift_diff_1, gift_diff_2, gift_diff_3))
```

What I'm hoping to do next is create a new column called `gift_closest` that would identify which of the ask amounts (ask1, ask2, or ask3) is closest in absolute value to the gift. We could use either the derived gift_diff columns or do it wholly within the equation. I can't get my head around how to best do it.

The value of the new column would be one of "ask1", "ask2", or "ask3". Ideally in a `dplyr` chain as that's where I'm creating the entire data set which will include a bunch of demographic fields.

thanks...

Comment: A non-dplyr pipe version - `avar <- c("ask1","ask2","ask3"); dfgive$closest <- avar[max.col(-abs(dfgive$gift - dfgive[avar]))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: I guess your `mindiff`-part won't do what you expect it to do. Replace `min` with `pmin`.

```r
library(dplyr)

dfgive %>%
  mutate(abs = pmin(abs(gift - ask1), abs(gift - ask2), abs(gift - ask3)),
         gift_close = case_when(abs(gift - ask1) == abs ~ "ask1",
                                abs(gift - ask2) == abs ~ "ask2",
                                abs(gift - ask3) == abs ~ "ask3",
                                TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

returns

```r
  id gift ask1 ask2  ask3 gift_diff_1 gift_diff_2 gift_diff_3 mindiff  abs gift_close
1  1   20   50  100   250         -30         -80        -230    -230   30       ask1
2  2 1000 5000 3750  2500       -4000       -2750       -1500   -4000 1500       ask3
3  3 1500 5000 3750  2500       -3500       -2250       -1000   -3500 1000       ask3
4  4  300  100  250   500         200          50        -200    -200   50       ask2
5  5  500 2500 5000 10000       -2000       -4500       -9500   -9500 2000       ask1
```

Comment: Ah...right. I'd seen `pmin` used in other versions of this question but wasn't seeing why it works the way it does. And was too deep into the idea I had to pull the value from the column name (like with `pivot_longer` or wider) rather than a `case_when` hard-code. This is great, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You might consider reshaping the data if you have many different `ask` columns, to reduce duplication of code. The result below can be joined back onto the original dfgive if you want to keep other columns in that dataframe.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dfgive <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  gift = c(20, 1000, 1500, 300, 500),
  ask1 = c(50, 5000, 5000, 100, 2500),
  ask2 = c(100, 3750, 3750, 250, 5000),
  ask3 = c(250, 2500, 2500, 500, 10000)
)

dfgive %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("ask"),
    names_to = "ask_num",
    values_to = "ask"
  ) %>%
  mutate(gift_diff = gift - ask) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(
    mindiff = min(gift_diff),
    gift_closest = ask_num[which.min(abs(gift_diff))]
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>      id mindiff gift_closest
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>       
#> 1     1    -230 ask1        
#> 2     2   -4000 ask3        
#> 3     3   -3500 ask3        
#> 4     4    -200 ask2        
#> 5     5   -9500 ask1
```

Comment: This is good too, but the df will already have a ton of rows because I'm analyzing across multiple appeals, multiple years. But this could work for pulling out subsets for making charts. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following solution which is predominantly based on `purrr` package functions beside the very good answers you received:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dfgive %>% 
  select(2) %>%
  map2_dfc(., dfgive %>% select(starts_with("gift_diff")), 
     ~ .x - abs(.y)) %>%
  set_names(~ paste("ask", 1:3, sep = "_")) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(gift_close = colnames(.)[max.col(cur_data())]) %>%
  select(gift_close) %>%
  bind_cols(dfgive) %>%
  relocate(gift_close, .after = last_col())


# A tibble: 5 x 10
# Rowwise: 
     id  gift  ask1  ask2  ask3 gift_diff_1 gift_diff_2 gift_diff_3 mindiff gift_close
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>     
1     1    20    50   100   250         -30         -80        -230    -230 ask_1     
2     2  1000  5000  3750  2500       -4000       -2750       -1500   -4000 ask_3     
3     3  1500  5000  3750  2500       -3500       -2250       -1000   -3500 ask_3     
4     4   300   100   250   500         200          50        -200    -200 ask_2     
5     5   500  2500  5000 10000       -2000       -4500       -9500   -9500 ask_1
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. Being facile with purrr is definitely a big gap in my r skills. I could do more with less code.

Comment: That's my pleasure. I really like `purrr` and learning to use its function will open up many possibilities when facing various problems.

Answer (score 2):

This you mutate directly using `cur_data`

```
dfgive %>% 
  mutate(gift_closest = {tmp <- str_detect(names(.), 'ask'); names(.[tmp])[max.col(-1 * abs(gift - cur_data()[tmp]))]})

  id gift ask1 ask2  ask3 gift_diff_1 gift_diff_2 gift_diff_3 mindiff gift_closest
1  1   20   50  100   250         -30         -80        -230    -230         ask1
2  2 1000 5000 3750  2500       -4000       -2750       -1500   -4000         ask3
3  3 1500 5000 3750  2500       -3500       -2250       -1000   -3500         ask3
4  4  300  100  250   500         200          50        -200    -200         ask2
5  5  500 2500 5000 10000       -2000       -4500       -9500   -9500         ask1
```

---

even you can proceed with generation of all new columns without the need of repeating it for every ask value

```r
dfgive <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), gift = c(20, 1000, 1500, 
                                                         300, 500), ask1 = c(50, 5000, 5000, 100, 2500), ask2 = c(100, 
                                                                                                                  3750, 3750, 250, 5000), ask3 = c(250, 2500, 2500, 500, 10000)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      -5L))
dfgive
#>   id gift ask1 ask2  ask3
#> 1  1   20   50  100   250
#> 2  2 1000 5000 3750  2500
#> 3  3 1500 5000 3750  2500
#> 4  4  300  100  250   500
#> 5  5  500 2500 5000 10000
library(tidyverse)
dfgive %>% 
  mutate(gift_closest = {tmp <- str_detect(names(.), 'ask'); names(.[tmp])[max.col(-1 * abs(gift - cur_data()[tmp]))]}) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('ask'), ~ gift - .,
                .names = 'gift_diff_{str_remove(.col,"ask")}')) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(mindiff = min(c_across(starts_with('gift_diff'))))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 10
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      id  gift  ask1  ask2  ask3 gift_closest gift_diff_1 gift_diff_2 gift_diff_3
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1     1    20    50   100   250 ask1                 -30         -80        -230
#> 2     2  1000  5000  3750  2500 ask3               -4000       -2750       -1500
#> 3     3  1500  5000  3750  2500 ask3               -3500       -2250       -1000
#> 4     4   300   100   250   500 ask2                 200          50        -200
#> 5     5   500  2500  5000 10000 ask1               -2000       -4500       -9500
#> # ... with 1 more variable: mindiff <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>